# Google Maps Not Showing up in my device

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-maps

Whenever i open Maps in My Ainol Tab It's Always Blank and after search it is 
showing no route found with error symbol:

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried reseting to factory Settings but unable to solve my issue

My tab Details :

[image: Tab Details]
<sup>Device Info (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Have you the latest version of Maps? Did it used to work?

Comment: Yeah I Have Updated It to Latest Version

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention a specific place in your city or even better, your current location. I'm sure there are more than a single bank with the same name in your city so it's better if you specify the branch too(typing your bank name should show the locations).

Anyways I opened Google Maps on my PC and searched the term "bank" and there was no bank of the name you searched. See [this link](http://goo.gl/maps/dgupV) for my exact search and the complete list.